# How to get sub category id by current category id in magento2

Tags: magento2, category, frontend

I want to get sub category id when I click on main category id. For ex. I Click on "Gear" category...Then It will also display sub category's id..

This is block file function :

```
public function getCurrentCategory(){        
$currentId  = $this->_registry->registry('current_category'); 
return $currentId; // it will return current category id}
```

This is phtml file :

```
    <?php 
$currentCategory = $block->getCurrentCategory();//I want to here subcategory id?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**To get child-category of sub-category Try below code :**

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    ...
}

public function getSubcategories()
{   
    $currentId  = $this->_registry->registry('current_category'); 
    $categoryObj = $this->categoryRepository->get($currentId->getId());
    $subcategories = $categoryObj->getChildrenCategories();

    //Print suncategory Ids
    foreach($subcategories as $subcategorie) {
        //echo $subcategorie->getId();
        if($subcategorie->hasChildren()) {
        $childCategoryObj = $this->categoryRepository->get($subcategorie->getId());
        $childSubcategories = $childCategoryObj->getChildrenCategories();
        foreach($childSubcategories as $childSubcategorie) {
            echo $childSubcategorie->getId();
        }
     }    
   }

    return $subcategories;
}
```

As its category collection so ,You can also use `$categoryObj->getPathId()` This function return all subcategory Ids of category.

Answer (score 1):

Inject `Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository` class to get subcategories

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    ...
}

public function getSubcategories()
{   
    $currentId  = $this->_registry->registry('current_category'); 
    $categoryObj = $this->categoryRepository->get($currentId->getId());
    $subcategories = $categoryObj->getChildrenCategories();

    foreach($subcategories as $subcategorie) {
        //echo $subcategorie->getId();
        if($subcategorie->hasChildren()) {
            $childCategoryObj = $this->categoryRepository->get($subcategorie->getId());
            $childSubcategories = $childCategoryObj->getChildrenCategories();
            foreach($childSubcategories as $childSubcategorie) {
                echo $childSubcategorie->getId();
            }
        }    
    }

    return $subcategories;
}
```

Comment: Yes....Your answer working for me....but it will give only last value..

Comment: See my commented foreach in answer it display multiple subcategory ids

Comment: There is one problem also..If I select "Men" Category then it will return only sub-category...That doesn't return child-category of sub-category.

Comment: Do you know how to get child-category of sub-category?

Comment: how to get subcategory image url in custom module block means i am calling block in phtml file and here i am trying to get subcategory image url magento 2